# How to get types from a nested object

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type that recognizes the strings of a nested object. However, trying to do so just returns me a type `string` instead of an array of particular strings. What is the correct way to implement this? Please see the code below. Thanks!

```
interface SampleInterface {
  allIds: string[];
  byId: {
    [key: string]: string[];
  };
}

const sampleObject: SampleInterface = {
  allIds: [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'alpha',
    'bravo',
    'charlie',
  ],
  byId: {
    foo: ['hello world'],
    bar: ['hello world'],
    alpha: ['hello world'],
    bravo: ['hello world'],
    charlie: ['hello world'],
  },
};

type ObjectKeys = keyof typeof sampleObject.byId;
// desired: type ObjectKeys = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'alpha' | 'bravo' | 'charlie';
// actual: type ObjectKeys = string;

const fn = (x: ObjectKeys) => console.log(x);

fn('test'); // no error is returned
```

Comment: Because `sampleObject` is of type `SampleInterface`, so `sampleObject.byId` is of type `{ [key: string]: string[] }` as that's how you defined the interface. So `keyof` gives you `string`. Try removing the `: SampleInterface` type annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sampleObject` is of type `SampleInterface`, since that's the type annotation you gave it. So `sampleObject.byId` is of type `{ [key: string]: string[] }` as that's how you defined the interface. It follows that `keyof typeof sampleObject.byId` is `string`.

The straightforward solution is to declare `sampleObject` without a type annotation, letting the compiler infer its type as specifically as possible.

That said, it would probably be better to also make `SampleInterface` generic, so that the type-checker enforces that the strings in `allIds` are the same as the property names of `byId`. If you want the constant's type to use `SampleInterface`, the best way to do it without repeated code is to declare the `byId` object first, declare the `ObjectKeys` type based on that object's keys, and then use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to dynamically create the `allIds` array.

```js
interface SampleInterface<K extends PropertyKey> {
  allIds: K[];
  byId: Record<K, string[]>
}

const _sampleObjectById = {
  foo: ['hello world'],
  bar: ['hello world'],
  alpha: ['hello world'],
  bravo: ['hello world'],
  charlie: ['hello world'],
};

// ObjectKeys = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'alpha' | 'bravo' | 'charlie'
type ObjectKeys = keyof typeof _sampleObjectById;

const sampleObject: SampleInterface<ObjectKeys> = {
  allIds: Object.keys(_sampleObjectById) as ObjectKeys[],
  byId: _sampleObjectById
}

// logs ['foo', 'bar', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']
console.log(sampleObject.allIds);
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpwLYAcA2ECS408SAPANLIQAekIAJgM7IAKUA9ltGAJ7kQ8AfMgDeAKGTI4OHPiYAuZOQDaAXQDcE5ACMecxQCUICdlHoUANMkZgooAOZrBYgL5ixJkDeQB9RplwIAHltACtjMAAhPXpkAF5RLRh2dkVlAHIACwgZdmQAd1McenTVCy1tOCg0rJycPMKoYtLyyWksTLga7NyCopKyiqg4ADdU5Aye+r6mgdbkBE6m4Ahuuob+ltdNMQB6XeQQ8IQwfh5mBPTk9nTkAB9kdMqoW4f09s7Xx+1hsa-0xZVHArdJiXhcQ5hCJnC7IADWAnYMGQ4IgSN8-mweCOEWich2nm8mMCOJOinQWIIRFgiAgpFJpwEjGECXEbRkckYigZADoEecABR+ALYqEnPH0ACUUmYDJhanmun0GJFwTFURirnc+2Q9XszAy13SVieVWNjw+cHNT1+NxNgOWEFKHnYXnYeB5eoFxNFxzAPOksiYkvUQA)